# Button onclick not completing function

Tags: javascript, html

I want my button to run two functions. It will run one, but not the other.

I've tried it both functions on their own and they work. When I try both functions with one button, it doesn't work.

```
<body>
    <input id="test" type="submit" value = "click me" onclick="deactivateFunc(); typewriter()">
    <script>
        var txt = "I made a typewriter.";
        var add = 0;
        var speed = 50;

        function typewriter() {
            if (add < txt.length)
                document.getElementById("test").innerHTML += txt.charAt(add);
            add++;
            setTimeout(typewriter, speed);
        }
        function deactivateFunc() {
            var btn = document.getElementById("test");
            btn.disabled = true;
            var myTimer = setTimeout(activate, 3000);
        }
        function activate() {
        var btn = document.getElementById("test");
        btn.disabled = false;
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

This properly disables and enables the button, but the typewriter function doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is running both functions, you're just not seeing the output of your `typewritter` because you're trying to set the `innerHTML` of an `input` element. Insead, set the innerHTML of another element such as a paragraph tag:

```html
<body>
  <p id="output"></p>
  <input id="test" type="submit" value="click me" onclick="deactivateFunc(); typewriter()">
  <script>
    var txt = "I made a typewriter.";
    var add = 0;
    var speed = 50;

    function typewriter() {
      if (add < txt.length) {
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += txt.charAt(add);
        add++;
        setTimeout(typewriter, speed);
      }
    }

    function deactivateFunc() {
      var btn = document.getElementById("test");
      btn.disabled = true;
      var myTimer = setTimeout(activate, 3000);
    }

    function activate() {
      document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
      add = 0;
      var btn = document.getElementById("test");
      btn.disabled = false;
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: So, I'm seeing the output of both functions now. But how do I go about making the typewriter function reset with the button? Right now the text stays when the button gets enabled. I want it to disappear so the button can run the function again.

Comment: In the deactivate function, set the output paragraphs innnerHTML to be “” and set add = 0. I’m on mobile now so I can’t edit the snippet and test sorry

Comment: This displays the function, but doesn't clear the text until after the button gets enabled and clicked. And then the text doesn't appear once the button gets clicked on again.

Comment: I found that by adding "document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = txt.charAt(add);" to the activate function, it will clear the text without having to click the button. But it still doesn't display the typewriter function more than once.

Comment: @MattBender you'll need to wrap everything in your `typewritter` function in the `if` statement you currently have, such that it only loops the typewritter when `add < length`. I've updated the snippet now if you want to take a look

Answer (score 1):

You should change `value` property of the button.

```
document.getElementById("test").value += txt.charAt(add);
```

Note - You should cancel the `setTimeout` for performance reasons

Answer (score 0):

As innerHTML of `input` tag don't meaning, I have added a `textarea` for testing, what can we help?

```
<body>
    <input id="test" type="submit" value = "click me" onclick="deactivateFunc(); typewriter()">
    <textarea id="test2"></textarea>
    <script>
        var txt = "I made a typewriter.";
        var add = 0;
        var speed = 50;

        function typewriter() {
            if (add < txt.length)
                document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML += txt.charAt(add);
            add++;
            setTimeout(typewriter, speed);
        }
        function deactivateFunc() {
            var btn = document.getElementById("test");
            btn.disabled = true;
            var myTimer = setTimeout(activate, 3000);
        }
        function activate() {
            var btn = document.getElementById("test");
            btn.disabled = false;
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try make an function that execute both of them

```
function myFunction(){
    function1();
    function2();
}
```

Comment: This was not the proble, since he called both of them already.